# Problem with SPIRIT1

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics

I am working in a design with the SPIRIT1 for RF communication: [image]

But many of them are working wrong, it looks like the SPIRIT1 dont biased correctly by the pin 14 and its inductors, has somebody work with this IC? some tips to debug it correctly?

Comment: How about some links to datasheets or reference manuals or something ... ?

Comment: We need more information to answer this question. What have you done already? How did it fail. Datasheets?

Comment: `working wrong` is meaningless without a description of expected behavior and a description of observed behavior